# How can i use a Hardware 2FA token within a SNAP app?

Tags: snap

I use the Google Advanced Security and it works fine on Ubuntu 20.04, however I cant access the hardware token from within a Snap app (Specifically YTM). Is there a switch on the snap I can use to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a U2F USB device, the snap needs to declare support for the [u2f-devices](https://snapcraft.io/docs/u2f-devices-interface) interface. Then you can [manually connect it](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management#heading--manual-connections).